# "'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for "PropertyName"

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, expandoobject, dynamicobject

I have the following code that generates Dynamic object from XML file:

**C#**

```
    private static List<dynamic> GetClientObject()
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(xmlPath + @"\client.xml"));
        dynamic root = new ExpandoObject();
        XmlToDynamic.Parse(root, xDoc.Elements().First());
        List<dynamic> clients = new List<dynamic>();

        for (int i = 0; i < root.clients.client.Count; i++)
        {
            clients.Add(new ExpandoObject());
            clients[i].Id = root.clients.client[i].id;
            clients[i].Name = root.clients.client[i].name;
            List<string> list = new List<string>();

            for (int j = 0; j < root.clients.client[i].emails.email.Count; j++)
            {
                list.Add(root.clients.client[i].emails.email[j].ToString());
            }

            clients[i].Email = string.Join(",", list);
        }
        return clients;
    }
```

**XML**

```
<clients>
    <client>
        <id>SomeId</id>
        <name>SomeName</name>
        <emails>
            <email>abc@xyz.com</email>
            <email>def@xyz.com</email>
            <email>ghi@xyz.com</email>
        </emails>
        <timezone>Mountain Standard Time</timezone>
    </client>
</clients>
```

The code works fine but I always see the following Exception(multiple times) in the IntelliTrace:

> Exception:Thrown: "'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a
>   definition for 'client'"
>   (Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException) A
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException was thrown:
>   "'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for
>   'client'"

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Looks like cycle condition should be root.clients.Count, not root.clients.client.Count

Comment: Please check updated XML format.

Comment: Without (a piece of) the XML it's impossible to tell if `root.clients.client.Count` makes any sense. Also, does the rest of the stacktrace refer to a line of your own code?

Comment: OK, for reference: http://www.itdevspace.com/2012/07/parse-xml-to-dynamic-object-in-c.html

Comment: No @HenkHolterman, stack-trace only refers to the Thread number and not to a line of code.

Comment: :D That is exactly what I have used to build this @HenkHolterman

Comment: I know, a link would have been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I gather this is expected behavior when using an `ExpandoObject`. I took a look at the IntelliTrace log for this code and the entries for the exceptions you are seeing are paired up:

- Exception:**Thrown**: "'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'clients'" (Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException)
- Exception:**Caught**: "'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'clients'" (Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException)

i.e. The exception is being thrown and then caught. If you look at the Call Stack Window you will see that the throws and catches are within the .NET Framework.

BTW, I did have to make a small change to your code to make it run:
I changed: `root.clients.client.Count` to `root.clients.Count` in the `for` loop.